# Чем пользоваться при планировке баз данных?

Tags: база-данных, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

При больших проектах какими инструментами пользуйтесь для планировки баз данных?

*Мне нужно визуализировать то что я буду делать в дальнейшем, мне нужен какой та инструмент для этого, созданная для этого*

Comment: Ну например у mysql есть MySQL Workbench. А вообще их куча и гуглятся легко.

Answer (score 2):

Бесплатных более менее нормальных инструментов я не нашел.
Из того чем пользовался:

1. ERwin
2. Toad Data Modeler
3. VISIO

Первые 2 позволяют генерировать скрипты на основании связей и типов, а третья- это просто способ нарисовать схему.

В Access и SSMS есть дизайнер, где можно задавать связи и типы.